# pgAgent missing as an option from Stack Builder

Tags: postgresql, installation, pgagent

I'm attempting to setup a new postgresql 9.6 installation.  I realize this is not the latest version but, due to some third party limitations, it's what I'm required to use.

The installation itself works just fine and I've been able to get my databases and FDWs installed without issue so I'm confident the database itself is OK.

The issue I'm having now is that I need to create a couple of scheduled jobs.  pgAgent seems to be a good option, I thought, however it's not showing as an option in the Stack Builder list.

I suppose I could go the route of installing it from source, but that's beginning to be way more work than I had hoped to have to do. Is there something I may be missing when doing the install?  I'm a bit stymied at this point.  Here's a shot of the screen that I'm seeing:

[image]

Again, this is a 9.6 install and, according to the docs, pgAgent **should** be an option, right?

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: `pgAgent` is part of `pgAdmin`. See here [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.29/pgagent.html). This is for latest version of `pgAdmin`, you may have to go to docs for your version to make sure nothing is different.

Comment: True but unfortunately pgAgent for a Windows target has only the source available.  I've had little luck with compiling it and was hoping to find a pre-compiled verion.
The docs clearly indicate that pgAgent is available from within the Stack Builder application but I showed in my original post, this is not the case for 9.6.